# MvvmCross 4.x vs MvvmCross 5.x

Tags: mvvmcross

We are currently running Mvx4.n and have a large client base for Win8 and iOS.  We will be writing an Android version soon and I can see that there has been a lot of activity around Android improvements.  We are not currently using Xamarin Forms but may do in a year or so.  I’m looking for a compelling reason to upgrade to Mvx 5 (but this would mean a separate code base for Win8 and UWP), but I can’t really see any at this stage.  Any suggestions or opinions either way would be appreciated.

Kind regards
Alan.

Answer (score 1):

If you are supporting a Windows Phone 8 app - I assume this is what you mean by Win8 - I would recommend that you do not upgrade to MvvmCross 5.x as Windows Phone 8 support has been removed. For more details [see the release notes here](https://www.mvvmcross.com/mvvmcross-5-release/)

Comment: UWP is still supported in 5.x. WP8 will also be removed in the next version of Xamarin.Forms, so i would recommend dropping that platform. It is always good to keep up to date, so in the end it would be better to update to 5.x

Comment: Thanks for your reply  Steve - we actually have an application on windows tablet devices - but still running Windows Store 8.1.  We have a few clients with many hundreds of these devices.  I realise that the only way to move to Mvx 5.n is to have two separate code bases - one for Win8.1 using Mvx 4.n and the other for UWP / Mvx 5.  What I really want to know is if there is a real compelling reason to move to Mvx 5 (with two code bases) for future android development?